# MVC multi tenant Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, attributes, multi-tenant

Hi I have a multi tenant application and my problem is, that tenant A has right to load the page and another tenant B not. I have on my ActionResult GetCars this attribute [AllowAnonymous], but tenant B has no right to access this page.

What is the best way to handle this situation? Can I overwrite this AllowAnonymous?

thanks for any ideas...

UPDATE

---

I use subdomains to identificate the tenants on the public sites... So tenant1.site.com can see the public sites and tenant2.site.com should not see the public sites...

UPDATE II

---

At the Moment I have this code in the BaseController, but i'm not happy about this...

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

        var cultureName = CultureHelper.GetNeutralCulture(CultureHelper.GetCurrentCulture());
        cultureName = CultureHelper.GetImplementedCulture(cultureName);
        filterContext.RouteData.Values["language"] = cultureName.ToUpper();

        var tenantDTO = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache["Tenant"] as TenantDTO;
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tenantDTO.SubDomain))
        {
            if (tenantDTO.SubDomain != "tenantB" && !Request.IsAuthenticated && !filterContext.RouteData.Values["Action"].Equals("DoLogin"))
            {
                filterContext.Result = RedirectToAction(AuthenticationController.DoLoginFunction, AuthenticationController.ControllerName, new { area = AuthenticationController.AreaName });
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to look at user roles https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ASPNET-MVC-5-Security-And-44cbdb97

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but in this case I can't use user roles, becouse the user is not logged in at this moment. In this case this are public sites which are taged as AllowAnonymous. Tenant A can is allowed to see this public sites and tenant B not.

Comment: I updated my question...

Comment: If it is public then it is public. You cannot stop people without a login, unless you know the IP address of tenant B. Then you could look at blocking by IP address.

Comment: yes I know, but I don't need the IP! I can handle that with the subdomain. If subDomain like Tenant B then redirect to login page...But if user is logged in he should not to be able to see this page when he paste the url in the browser... See Update II

Comment: "But if user is logged in he should not to be able to see this page" .... if they are logged in use user roles

Comment: Yes they are, so I can go on the user roles! thats a possibility...